# Can you benefit from Horde Breaker if you attack as part of Booming Blade or Green Flame Blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ranger

The [*booming blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade) and [*green-flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) cantrips from the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* both have the particularity of including a single melee weapon attack as part of their casting.

Several martial abilities, like Extra Attack or the Martial Arts’s bonus attack, do not work with these cantrips because they require the Attack action to be used.

However, the [Hunter Ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/ranger#Hunter)'s Horde Breaker ability (which lets you do an additional attack on another target with the same weapon once per turn) only requires an attack with a weapon, not necessarily the Attack action. Therefore, I’m wondering if a Hunter Ranger with Horde Breaker could get that additional-attack-on-different-target-with-same-weapon when using *booming blade* or *green-flame blade*.

Comment: Note, the answer mentioned in the bounty has been updated appropriately. The errata to *bb* and *gfb* did not affect the ruling in any way.

Comment: @Rykara I'm a bit confused by this bounty, is there some significant change to the answer that results from this errata?

Comment: @Rykara I don’t understand. What does the range of booming blade have to do with the range of my weapon?

Comment: @Rykara I don’t see how that question is related at all. Like, yeah, it’s a different answer, but that’s not irregular because it’s a totally unrelated question.

Comment: Yeah I’m not following. The other question has nothing to do with Horde Breaker so I don’t see how you’re using it to make a ruling about Horde Breaker. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 19):

### Yes

Horde Breaker states (PHB, p. 93, bold added):

> Once on each of your turns **when you make a weapon attack,** you can make another attack with the same weapon against a different creature that is within 5 feet of the original target and within range
> of your weapon.

For both *Green Flame Blade* and *Booming Blade*, you do make a weapon attack:

> You brandish the **weapon** used in the spell’s casting and make a **melee attack with it**

Note that you won't get any of the benefits of either spell a second time for the second attack, as explained in V2Blast's answer to this Q&A: [Can Green-Flame Blade be cast twice with the Hunter ranger's Horde Breaker ability?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/149052/62294)

Comment: I fully agree, but I think an improvement would be to say *why* the spell doesn't benefit the 2nd attack to close the loop.

Comment: Updated the spell description in the answer to match the Nov. 2020 Errata. The substance of the answer remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

The wording for the *booming blade*and  *green-flame blade* is:

> You brandish the weapon used in the spell’s casting and make a melee attack with it against one creature within 5 feet of you

Horde breaker requires you to make any melee attack, so the requirement for a melee attack is still met

Related, the spell doesn't work with the second attack is because spells do exactly what they say, no more no less, and this spell refers to this one specific attack, not to all attacks you do this turn

Comment: The answer you quote is not outdated. The quote in it is taken directly from the Errata’d version of *booming blade*.

Comment: oops i saw the bounty and got confused. Should i delete the answer?

Comment: You dont have to delete the answer, but I recommend reworking it so as not to be about the other answer. Up to you though.

Comment: Do you think this is better?

Comment: Yeah, looks fine.